# ClassicThesis, Lyx and PDFLatex: Font fvmro8r at 558 not found

Tags: fonts, pdftex, lyx, classicthesis

I am trying to get [ClassicThesis](http://code.google.com/p/classicthesis/) to work with Lyx. Installed the Bera and Mathpazo fonts in my local texmf tree and ran updmap:

```
~/texmf/bera/dvips/config$ sudo updmap --enable Map bera.map
[sudo] password for <username>: 
updmap: This is updmap, version $Id: updmap 14402 2009-07-23 17:09:15Z karl $
updmap: using transcript file `/home/<username>/.texmf-var/web2c/updmap.log'
updmap: initial config file is `/var/lib/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg'
```

However: when compiling the same error keeps popping up: !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file fvmro8r): Font fvmro8r at 558 not found

I'm running texlive2009 on Ubuntu 12.04 icm Lyx 2.0.0

Comment: Never use `updmap` along with `sudo`, for you're defining a map that's used only by root. Change `updmap` to `updmap-sys`

Comment: @egreg Please consider making your comment an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `updmap` script makes map files that are available only to the user who is issuing the command. Therefore

```
sudo updmap --enable Map bera.map
```

will produce map files valid for the user `root`. On some systems the map files might be stored in the "real" user home (from the transcript this can be the case for Ubuntu); however the file will probably not be readable without administrator privileges.

Always issue

```
sudo updmap-sys
```

for enabling new map files.

You should also remove the files created inside `~/.texmf-var`.